# GridView -out of range only in second page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to pass the index of row ...and it works great...but my gridview has paging enable and when I use the index in second page, for example, I'm getting Out of range error..but the index that I received its correct. For example..I have 4 rows in first page and 4 in second..If I click in first item of second page, I got index 5...it's correct. And I have 8 itens...why index 5 is getting out of range?

There's my code:

```
<asp:GridView  ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
            BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" CellSpacing="1" Width="100%" 
                GridLines="Vertical" AllowPaging="True" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
                onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
                onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" PageSize="5" HorizontalAlign=Left
                >
                                <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <RowStyle CssClass="tabela_texto2" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                                    VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="tabela_texto1" />

            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Button Text="Status" CommandName="atender" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="atender" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Tem certeza que deseja aterar os status?');" />

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Button Text="Ver no mapa" CommandName="ver" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="ver" runat="server"/>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

          <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Button Text="Excluir" CommandName="excluir" CommandArgument='<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex%>' ID="excluir" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Tem certeza que deseja aterar os status?');" />

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>


            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

and the line which is getting error is:

```
   protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            string commandname = e.CommandName;
            int index = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            if (commandname.Equals("atender"))
            {

                string id = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[3].Text //this line is getting error. 
}
}
```

Comment: Due to `Rows[index]` or `Cells[3]`? Remember the `index` is of the row in the grid, not the index of the element in the whole paged collection.

Comment: Rows[index] is the problem

Comment: There is no 4th cell. Try `Cells[2]`.

Comment: You might need something like `index % pageSize` here.

Comment: @SelvaTS the number of cells is the same of the first page....

Comment: @Chucrutes Have you tried with Cells[2]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a workaround:

```
int index = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString()) % GridView1.PageSize
```